# I cloned a Windows 10 laptop to an external SSD running on a pre-UEFI MacBook Air 2012

Tags: bootcamp, audio, windows, ssd, efi

I have no audio on my MacBook Air under Windows 10. Also some other problems typical for pre-UEFI MacBooks. I'm going to try to fix through DSDT (whatever that is) following [this tutorial.](http://www.itayemi.com/blog/2019/09/12/dual-booting-mac-osx-and-windows-on-macbookpro/)

...or using a script called valor somebody made on an Apple forum

But, they work through DSDT, and I took a file from my macOS, but I have no bootcamp partition. I just plug in my external SSD and boot. I don't understand the connection my windows will see with this file.

edit: here is link to the valor script thing, don't really know what the heck the guy concocted

http://www.howeitworks.com/valor

Comment: It would be helpful to know what "valor" is. At least a link to it, adding what you understand it does would also be a helpful addition. The more work you do in writing your question the more likely you will get a helpful answer.

Comment: sorry, I added link, didn't want to get too deep into it before any responses, I didn't expect many people to have heard of this issue of old macs without audio.

Comment: It is beyond my area of expertise, and it is possible no one here has seen your question or knows a possible answer, but we do have a number of people with a surprising amount of Mac knowledge, arcane and otherwise. I would keep looking elsewhere too and if you find the answer, you *can* answer your own question.